# Centre a label on a node in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'd like to be able to display a node with a particular label centred on the node - eg. a circle or rectangle node for instance with the label in the centre. This seems like it should be trivial and I'm sure it is but the relatively sparse documentation / tutorials on the web mean I can't seem to find the answer!

At the moment I can display a label on a node no problem (by default it appears so the top left of the label starts in the centre which isn't what I want) or set a label to appear to the right of the node (by setting a label "for" a particular node) but not position it in the middle! Can anyone shed some light on this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm betting your looking for something other then a layout, but the StackPane provides this type of functionality.

From the tutorial: [Working with Layouts](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG)

> StackPane
>
> The StackPane layout pane places all of the nodes within a single
>   stack with each new node added on top of the previous node. This
>   layout model provides an easy way to overlay text on a shape or image
>   or to overlap common shapes to create a complex shape. Figure 1-6
>   shows a help icon that is created by stacking a question mark on top
>   of a rectangle with a gradient background.

[image]

Code from the tutorial

Example 1-4 Create a Stack Pane

```
StackPane stack = new StackPane();
Rectangle helpIcon = new Rectangle(35.0, 25.0);
helpIcon.setFill(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
new Stop[]{
new Stop(0,Color.web("#4977A3")),
new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#B0C6DA")),
new Stop(1,Color.web("#9CB6CF")),}));
helpIcon.setStroke(Color.web("#D0E6FA"));
helpIcon.setArcHeight(3.5);
helpIcon.setArcWidth(3.5);

Text helpText = new Text("?   ");
helpText.setFont(Font.font("Amble Cn", FontWeight.BOLD, 18));
helpText.setFill(Color.WHITE);
helpText.setStroke(Color.web("#7080A0")); 

stack.getChildren().addAll(helpIcon, helpText);
stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);     // Right-justify nodes in stack

HBox.setHgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);    // Give stack any extra space
hbox.getChildren().add(stack);            // Add to HBox from Example 1-2
```

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I was looking for - I just wasn't looking in the right place! Thanks for that.